# What is the best way to handle concurrent sharing of configuration data

Tags: c++, multithreading, read-data

I am thinking to rewrite a monolithic C/C++ application (intially it was a single C++ executable) and I am trying to design my application to be more modular. I was thinking that I could deliver all my module as dll (or .so object on a linux platform) and compose my application at runtime instead of a single executable. Also I am seeking for modularity, I am doing my best to keep in mind that speed is either important for this application. So my deisgn should be a tradeoff between modularity and performance.

This is an IOT application, aimed to collect various data depending on the geolocalisation of the vehicle. 
 In my current application, there are 3 components :

[image]

1. AntennaService : this is the main service component of my application. This module would load the others. On every moove of the vehicle, it is querying a ConfigurationDataService to as it to return the most closest geo point indexed in a flat configuration file. And when needed it would fire event to log asynchronously via the log service.
2. LogService : a module service that is using the pub/sub mecansim to log asynchronously data either locally or online depending on the internet connection.
3. ConfigurationDataService : this is a module service that could potentially be called simultanisouly by various others component that are querying it about configuration to use. This module is reading some protocol buffers file where readonly configuration data is indexed. And depending on the query criteria asked by the others module, it filters or computer the static configuration data before anserwring.

The problem that I am facing then, is I do not find the best way to model the  ConfigurationDataService in order to have fast and optimal response :
 should it use lock and critical sections in order to respond to the parallel queries to the others modules ? Or do you think that there could be a far better design.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you shouldn't have any concurrency issues because you don't actually modify any data in the configuration service.

Comment: I would use std::mutex, std::unique_lock, std::lock_guard, std::condition_variable constructions to do all thread protection and timing that happens to be required by the specific design.  Trying hard to avoid them is a fools errand, and premature optimization. (in my opinion)